# Async pipe returns any type in WebStorm

Tags: angular, typescript, pipe, webstorm

I want to use the async pipe in my Angular 5 application. I'm defining an Observable with users in the controller. When I'm unwrapping this in the template using the async pipe the Angular Language Service does not recognize the type `UserModel` and appears to be using `any`.

My question: how do I get the async pipe to work with the types?

According to [this post](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/12398) it should work.

```
Angular: v5.5.1
Angular Language Service: v5.5.1
WebStorm: 2017.3.2
```

**What doesn't work:**

```
@Controller({})
export class MyController {
  users: Observable<UserModel[]>
  constructor() { this.users = userService.get() }
}
```

Template:

```
<div *ngFor="let user in users | async">{{ user.firstName + user.missing }}</div>
```

**My current alternative**

```
@Controller({})
export class MyController extends OnDestroy {
  private alive = true
  users: UserModel[]
  constructor() { 
    userService
      .get()
      .takeWhile(() => this.alive())
      .subscribe(users => this.users = users) 
  }
  ngOnDestroy() { this.alive = false; }
}
```

Template:

```
<div *ngFor="let user in users">{{ user.firstName + user.missing }}</div>
```

**EDIT:** implementation of `userService.get()`

```
get() { return this.http.get<UserModel[]>('api/users') )}
```

**EDIT2:** Added a plunkr. To be clear - I would like to get build errors and autocompletion working for properties on `user`. So: `user.name` should work fine, but `user.missing` should throw build errors.
    https://plnkr.co/edit/i9ggczzIFPEpP30KrcmE?p=preview

Comment: does it allow you to put a cast like as UserModel in the HTML template .. like : let user in (users | async) as USerModel or somethng like this

Comment: FWIW I can confirm it does recognize proper type for me.

Comment: @federicoscamuzzi no, it doesn't

Comment: @Zlatko What editor do you use?

Comment: Your alternative is strange and shouldn't be compiling, because you're putting `UserModel[]` in a variable supposed to contain `Observable<UserModel[]>`. Can you please show us the `userService.get()` method implementation?

Comment: @Supamiu You're right, that's a typo. I've added an example for the get() method.

Comment: @JesseBuitenhuis Also, I think you forgot to add the service in constructor.
Could you please provide a [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? I feel like you don't want to paste your whole code but the issue is probably in it, I don't feel like it's a webstorm issue, more like a typing-related issue.

Comment: @Supamiu I left it out for sake of focussing on the issue. I suspect it's probably an issue with Angular Language Service version in combination with Webstorm or Typescript version (2.5.3)

Comment: @Supamiu added a plunker!

Comment: By the way, what is the `@Controller({})` decorator?